# Highlight html/xml tags using only matchit and matchparen

Tags: highlight, plugin-matchit

I would like to highlight html and xml tags, but most plugins I find (e.g. vim-matchup) look like they do way more than I'd like, which I'd like to avoid. Is it possible to highlight the tags by using just the included matchit and matchparen? Since `%` works to jump from one another, I would just like to highlight these *one another*.

Comment: Maybe this one? https://github.com/gregsexton/MatchTag  => https://i.imgur.com/V2jBWW8.gif